# Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp', only while creating a build

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to use Firebase for Analytics but when I add **FirebaseApp.configure()** in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.

The Xcode gives Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'.

Strangely, if I build the code in simulator, it installs, but the error is generated only when I try to archive with Generic iOS device.

To solve this I tried replacing it with FireApp.configure() which can create the build but crashes when installed through TestFlight.

The deployment version in 10.0 for the app and Swift Version is 4.

It is compatible with latest version of Cocoapods.

Tried to replace **FirebaseApp.configure()** with  **FireApp.configure()**

Use of unresolved identifier '**FirebaseApp**'

Podfile is as follows

```
workspace 'Main.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

project 'A'
project 'B'
project 'C'
project 'D'

def common_pods
    pod 'Whisper', '~> 5.1.0'
    pod 'Gifu', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift', '~> 3.0.2'
    pod 'DKImagePickerController', '~> 4.0.4'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'HueKit'
    pod 'HanekeSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift.git'
    pod 'PKHUD', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'MZFormSheetPresentationController'
    pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift4'
    pod 'Locksmith'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'DeviceKit', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 3.7.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'TOCropViewController'
    pod 'Hero'
    pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 14.0.0'
    pod 'NewPopMenu', '~> 2.0'
    pod "QRCode"
    pod 'VVCircleProgressBar'
    pod 'PMAlertController'
    pod 'SwiftMessages', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages', :commit => '2e4381b61648a0451a7852b57bb0b4a82a4e6ce2'
    pod 'MaterialShowcase'  
end

target 'C' do
    project 'C/C.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Locksmith'
end

target 'B' do
    project 'B/B.xcodeproj'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Gifu', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift', '~> 3.0.2'
    pod 'DKImagePickerController', '~> 4.0.4'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'HanekeSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift.git'
    pod 'PKHUD', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'MZFormSheetPresentationController'
    pod 'DeviceKit', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 3.7.0'
    pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift4'
    pod 'TOCropViewController'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'Whisper', '~> 5.1.0'
end

target 'Main' do
    project 'Main.xcodeproj'
    common_pods
end

target 'D' do
    project 'D/D.xcodeproj'
    common_pods
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share your podfile?

Comment: Edited with the pod file

Answer (score 4):

I added `import FirebaseCore` then the issue has resolved

Comment: great! really annoying issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing Firebase into your class? Try `import Firebase`.

Since you have a lot of targets, might be something related to them. Which of your targets are you archiving?

Comment: *Strangely, if I build the code in simulator, it installs, but the error is generated only when I try to archive with Generic iOS device.* It would throw an error to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` if Firebase wasn't imported

Comment: I am archiving main target

Answer (score 0):

I added Firebase pods, in the Main project.